# Oracle - Take table information from crashed database

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have to take a table from a database. I have only the dbf files from this database, and it was NOT shuted down properly. The table hadn´t beeing changed just before the crash.

Is there a way of getting the information from this table from these datafiles?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a way?  Probably.  Is it cheap?  Nope.  Oracle Consulting has a recovery tool that they'll happily charge you an arm and a leg to use to try to recover data from a crashed database.  These folks http://www.ora600.be/ also have a tool.  My understanding is that they only charge an arm rather than an arm and a leg.  You can certainly get quotes from both but if the database wasn't important enough to back up properly, the data generally isn't valuable enough to make this worthwhile.

Comment: If it crashed can't you just start it up again? There must be more than just a crash that occurred... some corruption for instance?

Answer (score 0):

If using automatic UNDO_MANAGEMENT set it to MANUAL.